# Given a probability \mu,  can we always find a transformation T s.t. \mu is T-invariant?

Tags: ergodic-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, pr.probability, measure-theory

It is true that, under some conditions, given a measure-preserving transformation $T$, we can always construct a  $T$-invariant probability. I am wondering whether we can do a converse. See [Parry's Topics in ergodic theory p14](http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5291/5564946645_58634817f9_b.jpg)

Given a probability space $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$, can we always find a measure-preserving transformation $T:X \rightarrow X$ such that $\mu$ is $T$-invariant, except the identity?

Comment: The identity map.

Comment: You are right, I should exclude the identity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a counterexample to Jon's implicit rewording of your question, consider a purely atomic probability space in which the atoms all have different measure.

For a positive result, consider any purely non atomic probability space.  It is measure isomorphic to $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.  I guess for non separable purely non atomic probability spaces you just need to apply Maharam's classification theorem.

Comment: @Jon: In the category of measurable spaces and equivalence classes of non-singular maps every non-complete measurable space is equivalent to its completion.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. I was being silly... clearly, the right notion here is 'isomorphism mod 0'. 